# Regex catastrophic backtracking when not match

Tags: c#, regex, backtracking

I'm testing my regex in https://regex101.com/ before doing any coding.

Regex:

```
\[(.*?)\]((?:.\s*)*?)\[\/\1\]
```

Example string:

> [tag1]Test's Text Test Text Test Text Test Text.
>
> Test Text Test Text Test "Text Test Text" Test Text Test Text.
>
> Test Text? Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test
>   Text.
>
> Test Text, Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text
>   Test Text.[/tag1]
>
> [tag2]Test's Text Test Text Test Text Test Text.
>
> Test Text Test Text Test "Text Test Text" Test Text Test Text.
>
> Test Text? Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test
>   Text.
>
> Test Text, Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text
>   Test Text.[/tag2]
>
> ....
>
> ....

I'm trying to capture 2 group in some long strings. the first one is the text inside the square brackets and the second one is the text inside the tag.

The regex and string above don't have any problem when the regex is match. If in match, the steps taken are only 1000+ each match. But if the opening and the closing tag are not in match, catastrophic backtracking happens and the match is finished in 126.000+ steps and stopped finding the other matching strings.

I know, to prevent backtracking problem is to avoid using nested constructs that have "+" or "*" but I can't seem to know any better way to do this.

Maybe someone can offer or suggest a better regex than mine?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.... When does the problem occur?

Comment: Also, although I still don't understand your issue exactly, maybe try this regex? `\[([^]]+?)\]([^[]+)\[\/\1\]`

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. I just want a better regex than mine without affecting the performance later when I apply it to my code.

Comment: Though, more accurately: `\[([^\]]+?)\]([^\[]+)\[\/\1\]`

Comment: @Billvan Chandra A good way to prevent backtracking is using "atomic groups": http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html. Basically, the section in the atomic group `(?>)` will never backtrack.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the reference. I'll check it out to read more about it.

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer, you could accept the one that worked best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preface

First thing, use appropriate testing environment. If you use a regex in .NET, do not test it at a regex tester that does not support .NET regex.

**Regex101.com does NOT support .NET regex!**

You regex pattern does not cause any catastrophic backtracking with the string you posted at **[RegexStorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B(.*%3F)%5D((%3F%3A.%5Cs*)*%3F)%5C%5B%2F%5C1%5D&i=%5Btag1%5DTest%27s%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20%22Text%20Test%20Text%22%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%3F%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%2C%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%5B%2Ftag1%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5Btag2%5DTest%27s%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20%22Text%20Test%20Text%22%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%3F%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%2C%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%5B%2Ftag2%5D)**.

## Root cause

Ok, the regex pattern is really bad and inefficient. Why? The `(?:.\s*)*?` (enclosed in some larger pattern, as itself, standalone, it would not be a problem), matches any character followed with zero or more (thus, optional) whitespaces, all of that repeated 0 or more times, but as few as possible. So, both `.` and `\s*` can match the same string. When you wrap that in a group and add a quantifier, the total number of possible matching combinations that regex engine tries grows exponentially.

## Enhancing the pattern

The enhacement is not so evident, but many will come with a solution like the one given by Federico: use lazy dot matching pattern. So, `(?s)\[([^]]*)](.*?)\[/\1]` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B(%5B%5E%5D%5D*)%5D(.*%3F)%5C%5B%2F%5C1%5D&i=%5Btag1%5DTest%27s%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20%22Text%20Test%20Text%22%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%3F%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%2C%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%5B%2Ftag1%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5Btag2%5DTest%27s%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20%22Text%20Test%20Text%22%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%3F%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%2C%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%5B%2Ftag2%5D&o=s)) looks a viable solution. It yields 7,843 iterations per second at [RegexHero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

Using an unroll the loop method, we can boost the regex performance *n* times depending on the input. Here, we may write the `.*?` subpattern as any character but a `[` and any `[` not followed with `/\1]` up to the `\[/\1]`. This can be written with negated character classes and a lookahead inside 1 quantified group (it won't even require any modifiers or flags):

```
\[([^]]*)]([^[]*(?:\[(?!/\1])[^[]*)*)\[/\1]
```

See [this RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B(%5B%5E%5D%5D*)%5D(%5B%5E%5B%5D*(%3F%3A%5C%5B(%3F!%2F%5C1%5D)%5B%5E%5B%5D*)*)%5C%5B%2F%5C1%5D&i=%5Btag1%5DTest%27s%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20%22Text%20Test%20Text%22%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%3F%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%2C%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%5B%2Ftag1%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%5Btag2%5DTest%27s%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20%22Text%20Test%20Text%22%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%3F%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%20Text%2C%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text%20Test%20Text.%5B%2Ftag2%5D). This regex pattern yields 114,225 iterations per second. This is because there are no `[` at all in between `[tag1]` and `[/tag1]`, performance will get worse if a string contains a lot of `[` or consists of just `[` (which should not occur in real life).

## Testing

Here is RegexHero testing:

[image]

Your original regex yielded just 5,094 ips on that site.

Comment: Excellent tool. Didn't know that `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` was +20% faster than `\w+`

Comment: Well, these are not identical patterns in .NET. `\w`  matches all Unicode letters (with diacritics) and digits.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks! This answer definitely says a lot. After some testing, I can say that your regex is better. Mine won't match if there's "[" char in between the tag, though, there won't be any. I guess I'll read more about lookahead in regex. Also, care to explain why I shouldn't overescape my patterns? I thought I should escape all special chars to avoid syntax problem.

Comment: Overescaping impacts readability. It is advisable to only escape what must be escaped. If you feel unsure, you may escape special characters, though your pattern may grow twice as long due to backslashes. Use verbatim string literals at least.

Answer (score 1):

I think the catastrophic backtracking comes out because of this pattern:

```
(?:.\s*)*?
```

Having nested repetition within a group that can be repeated is always creating a pain for regex engines. Looking at your regex diagram it clear that your pattern is creating an ugly overhead:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You could improve your regex to have a pattern like this:

```
\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]        // Using single line flag
(?s)\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]    // Using inline single line flag
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS9iR6/1)**

Also you if you don't want to use single line flag you can use a little trick like this:

```
\[(.*?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/\1\]
```

Additionally, you might find useful using `+` (1 or more) operator instead of `*` (0 or more):

```
\[(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/\1\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that part out. I always know that pattern is the problem, but as I'm new to regex, I just can't think better off than the one I had. This definitely give me some insight about regex though.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this regex: `\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[\/\1\]` has significant less steps. Thanks for all the answers though.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZ9nX6/1)

Comment: First, you should not overescape your patterns. `[` as the first char in a character class does not have to be escaped, and `]` outside the char class does not have to be escaped. Then, `[^[]+` matches 1 or more characters other than `[` and what if there are `[` symbols in between `[tag1]` and `[/tag1]`? This regex won't work. And once again, do not use regex101 to test .NET regex. It will parse  `[\w-[az]]` pattern incorrectly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In other regex flavors [eg Java you'd have to escape](http://fiddle.re/9qx4ga) afaik. I would not say "overescaped" to a more compatible pattern. Of course something like `[][]` (what would work in pcre for matching square brackets) looks cool but indeed is not (to be honest I use too sometimes).

Comment: This pattern for square brackets comes from POSIX and is a very regexish regex. I wonder why JS, Java and ICU regex engines were deprived of this cool smart character placement in the character class.